# Mixing ASP.NET with ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

This might be a crazy question (I'm somewhat new to ASP.NET). But is it possible to mix ASP.NET code with classic ASP e.g. embedded a form created in ASP.NET in a classic ASP page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No you can not*

**asp pages** are basic simple pages that are actually running stand alone scripts on server side, and server returns the result. Every page is alone.

**asp.net pages** are a complete program that are connected together because they running under one pool, compile them all together in a single directory with many sub-directories, have special directories and other options. The pool that run the pages handle some common data, and session states, and many other thinks.

So you can have a full asp.net setup for your site, that first make it run, and then you can probably use some asp page to do some extra work until you transfer them all to asp.net

So the two are not have any relative together, so in simple answer **you can not embedd anything from one to the other**.

### Ways of sharing data between asp and asp.net

- You only can use iframe tricks to
  load one page into the other, but
  they still different and I do not like the idea.
- You use some ajax tricks to get and send data. No so cool idea also.
- You can use
  also a common database to share data.
- You can use same cookies to share
  data.
- You can not have the same session data (except with custom library for session like groat.com).
- You can share files.

### * Except if you code is so simple like

```
<% IF Len(SomeString) < 3 then %>
Ok something here
<% end if %>
```

In this case the code is simple running on both pages, but they are not embedded asp in asp.net, is complete render one page over one of the two.

[The #include Directive](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_incfiles.asp) is valid on both, but on asp.net is not going to compile the included file as on asp.

They have some common way of typing code but they are totally different, and you need start thinning different when you go to move from asp to asp.net

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the answer to your question is no.

However, in some cases, it may be possible to render part of an ASP.net page and then place the result into an ASP page.

I experimented with that a little bit last week using AJAX.

Here's what you can do.

Let's suppose that you have an ASP.net page with a form in it that you would like to render on an ASP page.

1) Create the ASP.net page with the form and wrap it in an ASP:Panel - give it an id: `pnlForm`
2) In your ASP.net codebehind, write the following code in `Page_Load`: `pnlForm.RenderControl()`.

```
System.IO.StringWriter stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
pnlReport.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
```

3) Add the following code snippet to the end of the codebehind:

```
// This snippet is neccessary to get ASP.net to render the report outsisde the page to write to an Excel spreadsheet.
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    return;
}
```

4) Create a blank `div` in your classic ASP page - give it the ID `formDiv`.

5) On the classic ASP page, use jQuery.ajax to fetch the form and place it on the classic ASP page:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "myASPdotNetpage.aspx",
 success: function(response) { $('#formDiv').html(response); }
});
```

As you can imagine, this is not exactly how the framework is meant to be used, but if you really need to render some ASP.net and put it somewhere else (such as on an ASP page, or even a spreadsheet sometimes), you can at least capture the HTML.

Comment: This is probably not how MS designed ASP.net to be used, but it's absolutely invaluable for dropping ASP.net gridview objects wherever I feel like putting them.

Comment: Dont know if anyone's still reading this, but instead of using ajax in your Classic ASP page you could pull your content on the server side with ServerXMLHTTP

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The major issue is that ASP and ASP.NET run in different processes. You can have a stand alone ASP page within an ASP.NET application but you are not going to be able to share any code between them. In essence you would have two applications running in the same directory. There is no way to share any data which is stored in one process (for example Session data).

Comment: ASP and ASP.net run in different processes.  They each have their own session, but you are incorrect to say that they cannot share data.  In my environment, we commonly accomplish this using SQL server.  There are tools that are designed to facilitate this: See GROAT SessionFarm for example

Comment: Bit unfair voting this down, they are correct "you are not going to be able to share any code between them" as the two are different technology stacks. I think maybe "data" has been misconstrued in this instance, any web app can share data with any other web app, that is a universal constant of how HTTP works (shared server data sources, cross-origin scripts and standard dtos (XML and other formats)).